# Primary key constraint gets removed when creating postgres table from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, sql, pandas, postgresql

I am trying to create few tables in Postgres from pandas dataframe but I am kept getting this error.

```
 psycopg2.errors.InvalidForeignKey: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "titles"
```

After looking into this problem for hours, i finally found that when I am inserting the data into parent table from pandas dataframe, the primary key constraint gets removed for some reasons and due to that I am getting this error when trying to refernece it from another table.

But I am not having this problem when I am using pgAdmin4 to create the table and inserting few rows of data manually.

[image]
[image]

you can see when I created the tables using pgAdmin, the primary key and foreign keys are getting created as expected and I have no problem with it.

But when I try to insert the data from pandas dataframe using psycopg2 library, the primary key is not getting created.

I Can't able to understand why is this happening.

[image]

The code I am using to create the tables -

```
# function for faster data insertion
def psql_insert_copy(table, conn, keys, data_iter):
    """
    Execute SQL statement inserting data

    Parameters
    ----------
    table : pandas.io.sql.SQLTable
    conn : sqlalchemy.engine.Engine or sqlalchemy.engine.Connection
    keys : list of str
        Column names
    data_iter : Iterable that iterates the values to be inserted
    """
    # gets a DBAPI connection that can provide a cursor
    dbapi_conn = conn.connection
    with dbapi_conn.cursor() as cur:
        s_buf = StringIO()
        writer = csv.writer(s_buf)
        writer.writerows(data_iter)
        s_buf.seek(0)

        columns = ", ".join('"{}"'.format(k) for k in keys)
        if table.schema:
            table_name = "{}.{}".format(table.schema, table.name)
        else:
            table_name = table.name

        sql = "COPY {} ({}) FROM STDIN WITH CSV".format(table_name, columns)
        cur.copy_expert(sql=sql, file=s_buf)


def create_titles_table():
    # connect to the database
    conn = psycopg2.connect(
        dbname="imdb",
        user="postgres",
        password=os.environ.get("DB_PASSWORD"),
        host="localhost",
    )
    # create a cursor
    c = conn.cursor()

    print()
    print("Creating titles table...")
    c.execute(
        """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS titles(
                title_id  TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
                title_type  TEXT, 
                primary_title  TEXT, 
                original_title  TEXT,
                is_adult  INT, 
                start_year  REAL, 
                end_year  REAL, 
                runtime_minutes REAL
                )
    """
    )
    # commit changes
    conn.commit()

    # read the title data
    df = load_data("title.basics.tsv")
    # replace \N with nan
    df.replace("\\N", np.nan, inplace=True)
    # rename columns
    df.rename(
        columns={
            "tconst": "title_id",
            "titleType": "title_type",
            "primaryTitle": "primary_title",
            "originalTitle": "original_title",
            "isAdult": "is_adult",
            "startYear": "start_year",
            "endYear": "end_year",
            "runtimeMinutes": "runtime_minutes",
        },
        inplace=True,
    )
    # drop the genres column
    title_df = df.drop("genres", axis=1)
    # convert the data types from str to numeric
    title_df["start_year"] = pd.to_numeric(title_df["start_year"], errors="coerce")
    title_df["end_year"] = pd.to_numeric(title_df["end_year"], errors="coerce")
    title_df["runtime_minutes"] = pd.to_numeric(
        title_df["runtime_minutes"], errors="coerce"
    )

    # create SQLAlchemy engine
    engine = create_engine(
        "postgresql://postgres:" + os.environ["DB_PASSWORD"] + "@localhost:5432/imdb"
    )
    # insert the data into titles table
    title_df.to_sql(
        "titles", engine, if_exists="replace", index=False, method=psql_insert_copy
    )

    # commit changes
    conn.commit()
    # close cursor
    c.close()
    # close the connection
    conn.close()
    print("Completed!")
    print()


def create_genres_table():

    # connect to the database
    conn = psycopg2.connect(
        dbname="imdb",
        user="postgres",
        password=os.environ.get("DB_PASSWORD"),
        host="localhost",
    )

    # create a cursor
    c = conn.cursor()

    print()
    print("Creating genres table...")
    c.execute(
        """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS genres(
            title_id  TEXT NOT NULL, 
            genre  TEXT,
            FOREIGN KEY (title_id) REFERENCES titles(title_id)
            )
    """
    )
    # commit changes
    conn.commit()

    # read the data
    df = load_data("title.basics.tsv")
    # replace \N with nan
    df.replace("\\N", np.nan, inplace=True)
    # rename columns
    df.rename(columns={"tconst": "title_id", "genres": "genre"}, inplace=True)
    # select only relevant columns
    genres_df = df[["title_id", "genre"]].copy()
    genres_df = genres_df.assign(genre=genres_df["genre"].str.split(",")).explode(
        "genre"
    )

    # create engine
    engine = create_engine(
        "postgresql://postgres:" + os.environ["DB_PASSWORD"] + "@localhost:5432/imdb"
    )

    # insert the data into genres table
    genres_df.to_sql(
        "genres", engine, if_exists="replace", index=False, method=psql_insert_copy
    )

    # commit changes
    conn.commit()
    # close cursor
    c.close()
    # close the connection
    conn.close()
    print("Completed!")
    print()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    print()
    print("Creating IMDB Database...")
    # connect to the database
    conn = psycopg2.connect(
        dbname="imdb",
        user="postgres",
        password=os.environ.get("DB_PASSWORD"),
        host="localhost",
    )

    # create the titles table
    create_titles_table()

    # create genres table
    create_genres_table()
    # close the connection
    conn.close()
    print("Done with Everything!")
    print()
```

Comment: The issue is your inconsistent use of capitalization in your column names.  If you are going to create columns with capital letters, you will always need to double quote them.  Please avoid using capital letters.  Use title_id, title_type, etc. instead.  It will avoid many headaches.

Comment: Hi @Jeremy , i  renamed all the columns as you suggested but still getting the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is `to_sql(if_exists="replace")`. Try using `to_sql(if_exists="append")` - my understanding is that "replace" drops the whole table and creates a new one with no constraints.